# How to replace component-scoped service with spy object in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, scope, jasmine, angular-services

Currently I'm (Context: I am Angular beginner) developing a simple login-screen in a larger project with Angular 6 also using jasmine-tests. For the communication with the backend we use websockets which connect to different endpoints. For that reason I have to define component-scoped providers for two services:

```
// user-password-form.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-password-form',
  templateUrl: './user-password-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-password-form.component.scss'],
  providers: [WebSocketService, AuthenticationService]
})
```

Now I want to test some functionality of `user-password-form.component.ts` by mocking `AuthenticationService` which uses `WebSocketService`. WebSocketService is also used by different other Services. The user-password-form.component only uses `AuthenticationService`, but due to the hierarchic DI, I also have to provide the WebSocketService at the component scope in order to receive an own instance.

Now, with jasmine, I want to test the functionality of the component by defining the following spec

```
const authServiceSpy
    = jasmine.createSpyObj('AuthenticationService', ['authenticate']);


  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [UserPasswordFormComponent],
      providers: [LoggerService, FormBuilder,
        {provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: authServiceSpy}
      ],
      imports: [RouterModule],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
```

However, in this case the spy isn't injected instead of the real authenticationService. Consequently, I am not able to run the following line:

```
expect(authService.authenticate.calls.mostRecent().args[0]).toEqual(authObj);
```

How can I force the Injection-mechanism to use the spyObject instead of the real AuthenticationService for the purpose of unit testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach cannot work, because you replace the `AuthService` at the `TestBed` level, and the service is provided at the component level.

You can completely replace the provider with `TestBed.overrideProvider`.

Try this:

```
TestBed.overrideProvider(AuthenticationService, { useValue: authServiceSpy });
```

Also, make sure to call `TestBed.compileComponents()` after overriding the provider.